# Formatting table lines in landscape using tabularx: they stop halfway through

Tags: tables, tabularx, rules, landscape

The lines in the table somehow stop halfway through the table. Any advice would be much appreciated!

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{book}
\usepackage{booktabs} 
\usepackage{tabularx} 
\usepackage{pdflscape} 

\begin{document}
\begin{landscape}
    \begin{table*}
    \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{}lcccccccccccr@{}}
        \toprule
        & Control&    &     & Low Input & &      & Medium Input & &    & High Input &  &    \\
        & Mean  & SD  & N   & Mean & SD   & N    & Mean & SD   & N     & Mean & SD  & N     \\
        \midrule                    

        Fillers posttest I             & 78.0 & 6.58 & 20  & 84.1 & 10.1 & 48   & 86.2 & 10.9 & 46   & 84.0 & 11.5 & 21 \\ 
        Fillers posttest II            & 86.1 & 9.41 & 20  & 91.2 & 9.5  & 48   & 95.3 & 7.71 & 46   & 90.5 & 8.25 & 21 \\              

        Plural Nouns posttest I        & 50.8 & 17.0 & 20  & 50.3 & 18.2 & 48   & 55.0 & 17.7 & 46   & 60.0 & 23.9 & 21 \\
        Plural Nouns posttest II       & 55.5 & 26.9 & 20  & 56.3 & 19.3 & 48   & 62.6 & 22.4 & 46   & 61.9 & 20.9 & 21 \\
        Present Simple posttest I      & 36.4 & 12.5 & 20  & 40.3 & 19.5 & 48   & 39.7 & 18.9 & 46   & 32.3 & 15.7 & 21 \\ 
        Present Simple posttest II     & 25.1 & 23.3 & 20  & 27.8 & 18.0 & 48   & 23.5 & 17.5 & 46   & 38.6 & 19.2 & 21 \\

        Present Progressive posttest I & 36.0 & 20.5 & 20  & 41.4 & 18.7 & 48   & 41.0 & 16.8 & 46   & 40.5 & 17.3 & 21 \\
        Present Progressive posttest II& 30.4 & 26.7 & 20  & 28.5 & 18.7 & 48   & 26.1 & 19.8 & 46   & 33.8 & 24.7 & 21 \\
        \bottomrule
    \end{tabularx}
\end{table*}
\end{landscape}
\end{document}
```

Which results in :[image]

Answer (score 9):

You have two problems:

- `textwidth` is on the `landscape` orientation the same as in the `portrait˛`. so lines are long only `textwidth`
- if you use `tabularx` at least one colum. had to be type `X`

if you replace line with

```
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{}lcccccccccccr@{}}
```

width for example with

```
\begin{tabularx}{\hsize}{@{}Xcccccccccccr@{}}
```

or shorter:

```
\begin{tabularx}{\hsize}{@{}X*{11}{c}r@{}}
```

the table will become as you expected (I guess). I obtain:

[image]

For having just one line in each row in the first column, you need to tweak inter column spacing or make reformat column heads for `Medium Input` and `Height Input` or make table a bit wider, for example for width use `1.05\hsize`.

**addendum:**
after two and half years i look your table again ... now seems to me, that you actually make sense the following redesign of your table:

[image]

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{book}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{booktabs, tabularx}
\newcommand\mccc[1]{\multicolumn{3}{c}{#1}}% <-- added

\begin{document}
\begin{landscape}
\begin{table}
\setlength\tabcolsep{9pt}
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{@{}X*{12}{c}@{}}<-- changed
    \toprule
    & \mccc{Control} & \mccc{Low Input} & \mccc{Medium Input} & \mccc{High Input}       \\
    \cmidrule(lr){2-4}  % <-- added
    \cmidrule(lr){5-7}  % <-- added
    \cmidrule(lr){8-10} % <-- added
    \cmidrule(lr){11-13}% <-- added
    & Mean  & SD  & N   & Mean & SD   & N    & Mean & SD   & N     & Mean & SD  & N     \\
    \midrule
Fillers posttest I
    & 78.0 & 6.58 & 20  & 84.1 & 10.1 & 48   & 86.2 & 10.9 & 46   & 84.0 & 11.5 & 21 \\
Fillers posttest II
    & 86.1 & 9.41 & 20  & 91.2 & 9.5  & 48   & 95.3 & 7.71 & 46   & 90.5 & 8.25 & 21 \\
Plural Nouns posttest I
    & 50.8 & 17.0 & 20  & 50.3 & 18.2 & 48   & 55.0 & 17.7 & 46   & 60.0 & 23.9 & 21 \\
Plural Nouns posttest II
    & 55.5 & 26.9 & 20  & 56.3 & 19.3 & 48   & 62.6 & 22.4 & 46   & 61.9 & 20.9 & 21 \\
Present Simple posttest I
    & 36.4 & 12.5 & 20  & 40.3 & 19.5 & 48   & 39.7 & 18.9 & 46   & 32.3 & 15.7 & 21 \\
Present Simple posttest II
    & 25.1 & 23.3 & 20  & 27.8 & 18.0 & 48   & 23.5 & 17.5 & 46   & 38.6 & 19.2 & 21 \\
Present Progressive posttest I
    & 36.0 & 20.5 & 20  & 41.4 & 18.7 & 48   & 41.0 & 16.8 & 46   & 40.5 & 17.3 & 21 \\
Present Progressive posttest II
    & 30.4 & 26.7 & 20  & 28.5 & 18.7 & 48   & 26.1 & 19.8 & 46   & 33.8 & 24.7 & 21 \\
    \bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
\end{table}
\end{landscape}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Change `\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{@{}X*{12}{c}@{}}<-- chaned` to `\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{@{}X*{12}{c}@{}} %<-- changed` in the addendum

Comment: @Mammoth, done! Thank you for inform me for this spelling error,

Answer (score 1):

[image]

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{book}
\usepackage{booktabs} 
\usepackage{tabularx} 
\usepackage{pdflscape} 
\begin{document}    
\begin{landscape}

\renewcommand{\tabcolsep}{5pt}
\begin{table*}
    \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{@{}X*{11}cr@{}}
        \toprule
        & Control&    &     & Low Input & &      & Medium Input & &    & High Input &  &    \\
        & Mean  & SD  & N   & Mean & SD   & N    & Mean & SD   & N     & Mean & SD  & N     \\
        \midrule    
        Fillers posttest I             & 78.0 & 6.58 & 20  & 84.1 & 10.1 & 48   & 86.2 & 10.9 & 46   & 84.0 & 11.5 & 21 \\ 
        Fillers posttest II            & 86.1 & 9.41 & 20  & 91.2 & 9.5  & 48   & 95.3 & 7.71 & 46   & 90.5 & 8.25 & 21 \\     
        Plural Nouns posttest I        & 50.8 & 17.0 & 20  & 50.3 & 18.2 & 48   & 55.0 & 17.7 & 46   & 60.0 & 23.9 & 21 \\
        Plural Nouns posttest II       & 55.5 & 26.9 & 20  & 56.3 & 19.3 & 48   & 62.6 & 22.4 & 46   & 61.9 & 20.9 & 21 \\
        Present Simple posttest I      & 36.4 & 12.5 & 20  & 40.3 & 19.5 & 48   & 39.7 & 18.9 & 46   & 32.3 & 15.7 & 21 \\ 
        Present Simple posttest II     & 25.1 & 23.3 & 20  & 27.8 & 18.0 & 48   & 23.5 & 17.5 & 46   & 38.6 & 19.2 & 21 \\
        Present Progressive posttest I & 36.0 & 20.5 & 20  & 41.4 & 18.7 & 48   & 41.0 & 16.8 & 46   & 40.5 & 17.3 & 21 \\
        Present Progressive posttest II& 30.4 & 26.7 & 20  & 28.5 & 18.7 & 48   & 26.1 & 19.8 & 46   & 33.8 & 24.7 & 21 \\
        \bottomrule
    \end{tabularx}
\end{table*}

\end{landscape}
\end{document}
```

First, replace `\textwidth` by `\linewidth` because `\textwidth` is on the landscape orientation the same as in the portrait orientation (also mentioned by @Zakro).

Second, your table is only wider than `\linewidth` by about `25pt`. The number of columns is `13`, which should have `26\tabcolsep`'s minus `2\tabcolsep`'s caused by two `@{}`. So, we can shrink the `\tabcolsep` by only `1pt` (will not be even noticable) from the original width. This will gain us about `24pt` in width. Finally use at least one column with the `X` specification, then your table fits with no errors or warnings.